# How to allow my view to display duplicate results for the title field?

Tags: views

In a content pane view i have excluded my title from the display.
Instead i have grouped the title under fields configurations.

My problem is that for some reason my view isn't allowing any duplicate results for the title.
I have made sure that under query settings the distinct is unchecked.

What other setting could cause this behaviour?

Comment: it will not show duplicate because you have grouped the title

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize the exact function of grouping.

Comment: Glad to see that you have got it :)